# Simperium read-only API Key allows writing to cloud

Tags: simperium

I expected when initiating the simperium instance with the read-only key that I created that my application could read from the cloud storage but not write to it. I'm still able to write when using a read-only key. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Simperium doesn't offer a readonly API key. Instead, it has the 'Default' and 'Admin' keys.
The difference between them is:

- Default key is used to generate tokens for user access
- Admin key can be used by your own backend, and would allow you to sync data for multiple users.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.simperium.com/overview/) (Section: 'Access Tokens and API Keys').